# Calculate field of view of simple polygon from a point

Tags: math, geometry, polygon, computational-geometry

Given a non-self-intersecting polygon as a list of points (p<sub>1</sub>...p<sub>n</sub>), and a point (A) outside that polygon:

I want to calculate the total angular field of view covered by the polygon from the point, as well as the direction from the point towards the middle of that field of view (as either a vector or angle from horizontal).

Visually, I want the angle Θ and direction of the green vector:

[image: Diagram of a black polygonal shape roughly looking like a horizontally mirroed letter C. points are labelled p1 to p2. There is a point labelled A roughly vertically centred with the C shape and horizontally closer to the centre of the C shape but no intersecting it. point A also has a angle Θ annotated, covering the angle range from the top left point to the bottoem left point: an angle > 180 degrees. There is also a green arrow visualising the direction of A towards the middle of the shape.]

I tried finding the minimum and maximum angles from horizontal to each of the polygon points, but I don't know how to tell which is the start of the range and which is the end. Assuming the smaller angle is the start gives incorrect results from the left of a simple box.

I'm guessing the solution will have something to do with whether the polygon points are in clockwise or counterclockwise order.

Answer (score 1):

Whether the polygon goes clockwise or counterclockwise doesn't matter. What matters is that the extent of any edge, as seen from the point, must be less than π radians. That will tell us whether the edge -- as seen from the point -- goes counterclockwise from A to B, or from B to A.

For example, suppose the bearings (in radians) from the point to the vertices are {0, 2π/5, 4π/5, 6π/5, 8π/5}. If the edges are represented by the (unordered) pairs (A,C), (A,E), (B,D), (B,E), (C,D). Then the edges run:

```
0->4π/5
2π/5->6π/5
4π/5->6π/5
8π/5->0
8π/5->2π/5
```

So the range of the polygon is [8π/5, 6π/5].

Comment: I don't think I understand the procedure you used to get that range from the polygon. Could you elaborate?

Comment: @Earlh21: The vertices alone are not enough to give the range; we must know which pairs of vertices are joined by edges. If we know that A(0) and E(8π/5) are connected, then we know that of those two vertices, A is the "more counterclockwise" and E is the "less counterclockwise". We do that for all of the edges, and then we can (partially) order the vertices by "counterclockwiseness": D is the most, and E is the least. So the range of the polygon is [E, D]. If any part of that is still unclear, I will edit the answer.